# En C#, ¿cómo detecto si he pulsado en un pictureBox y en cuál de ellos he pulsado?

Tags: c#, picturebox

He generado unos pictureBox con un código de Eduardo Reyes dentro de un panel que activo y desactivo pero no soy capaz de que los pictureBox estén activos y generar una acción al pulsar sobre ellos.
El código para generar los pictureBox es este:

```
while (registro.Read())
{
    NumeroMiniatura = "00000" + registro["NUMERO"].ToString();
    NumeroMiniatura = NumeroMiniatura.Substring(NumeroMiniatura.Length - 6, 6);
    string MidresImagen = "Z:\\Midres\\Midres" + NumeroMiniatura.Substring(0, 2) + "\\" + NumeroMiniatura + ".jpg";
    PictureBox pictureBox_miniatura = new PictureBox();
    //Esta linea establece un tamaño del pictureBox_miniatura, que puedes adecuar al tamaño de tus miniatura
    pictureBox_miniatura.Size = new Size(dimensionbox, dimensionbox);
    pictureBox_miniatura.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    //Esta linea establece la coordenada superior del pictureBox_miniatura, para evitar que se apilen unos sobre otros
    pictureBox_miniatura.Location = new Point((pictureBox_miniatura.Width + 2) * i, (pictureBox_miniatura.Width + 2) * fila);
    pictureBox_miniatura.Image = null;
    pictureBox_miniatura.Image = Image.FromFile(MidresImagen);
    //Esta linea agrega el pictureBox_miniatura al panel contenedor
    panel1.Controls.Add(pictureBox_miniatura);
    i++;
    if (i > columnas) { fila++; i = 0; }
}
```

Funciona como yo quiero pero necesito detectar que he pulsado en uno de los pictureBox.

Comment: Y necesitas agregarle eventos a esos picturebox.. como si no lo hubieras hecho por codigo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que los [`PictureBox`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) tienen el evento [`Click`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.click?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) puedes suscribirte a él en cada control. De modo que cuando alguno sea cliqueado una función sea llamada.

Por ejemplo:

```
void PictureBoxClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (sender is PictureBox pb){
        // Haces lo que tengas que hacer
        ...
    }
}
```

Y en el `while`, cuando configuras el `PictureBox` agregas:

```
pictureBox_miniatura.Click += PictureBoxClicked;
```

De forma similar, puedes hacer lo mismo con diferentes eventos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me pongo a ello.

Comment: Genial, a la primera, muchas gracias.